# How can I send simple variables to a website with Python

Tags: database, python-3.x

Lets say I had a Python script that determined the users favorite fruit, then sent the data:

> fruit = apple

to a website named apples.com

How can I do this?

Also, If you can, can you explain the web end of the exchange, or should I make another post for that?

I am not sure which tags to use, so recommendations are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The question is pretty vague. You could take a look at the request module to send POST request to the website. The data could be enconde in json format. You'll need to have some sort of API on the website to use the received data. You can make a simple app with [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).